# How to make voxel (pixelated) explosion,smoke,etc

Tags: smoke-simulation

I want to make some sort of pixelated animation but i need to make a pixelated smoke and explosion as well, but i don't know how to make
this voxel smoke style or explosion,
this is how it looks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar3sSawyR1c i really don't know how to create this effect... is so simple to look at it but in blender i am not sure how to make the smoke simulation or explosion to look like this... even on youtube there's is no tutorial for this. if anyone knows how to make this i would really be appreciated.

Comment: well, i agree... but i dont know how to search it, i tried many ways, for example: explosion voxel pixelated and others, but i am still don't find something.

Comment: Anyways are you satisfied with the link provided?

Comment: @Yash is your link correct? I just get the original footage ...

Comment: Oh sorry my apologies I provided the wrong link. Here it is https://youtu.be/hdVKfDim7p0 @RobinBetts

Comment: oh thanks!, but to get the effect of the "pixels" i have to low the resolution of smoke?

Comment: In tutorial it is shown to use UV Sphere for emitter particles right, if you want it pixelated you may use cubes instead.